# Glassfish 2.1 plugin for eclipse helios doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, glassfish-2.x

JDK 1.5_22 (32 bit ) , eclipse Helios  ( 32 bit ).I am in need of glassfish 2.1 plugin for eclipse .I get the error 404 while accessing the URL http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios. Please help me

Comment: I think you are going to struggle, Glassfish 2.1 is very old

Comment: Yes in our scope we have a project that was built on 2.1 itself , so it's compatible with that version alone.:( Looking for some solutions

Comment: What features are you looking for in the plugin ?
Just deploy ?

Comment: For debug you can start Glassfish with the debug parameters of Java 5 and attach a debugger in Eclipse.
In your build you can drop the WAR or EAR in the autodeploy directory.
This won't be a first prize, but at least your IDE can be something newer than a stone age Eclipse IDE.
It will satisfy Debug,Run,Deploy.